# How to assert data type with Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my Node application.

Is it possible for me to expect/assert a value to be a Date Object?

`expect(typeof result).toEqual(typeof Date())`

Was my attempt, but naturally returns [Object]. And so this would pass too {}.

Thanks!

Answer (score 193, accepted):

**for Jest with newer version `> 16.0.0`:**

There is a new matcher called `toBeInstanceOf`. You can use the matcher to compare instances of a value.

**Example:**

```js
expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(Date)
```

---

**for Jest with version `< 16.0.0`:**

Use `instanceof` to prove whether the `result` variable is a `Date` Object or Not.

**Example:**

```js
expect(result instanceof Date).toBe(true)
```

---

**Another example to match common types:**

**`boolean`**

```js
expect(typeof target).toBe("boolean")
```

**`number`**

```js
expect(typeof target).toBe("number")
```

**`string`**

```js
expect(typeof target).toBe("string")
```

**`array`**

```js
expect(Array.isArray(target)).toBe(true)
```

**`object`**

```js
expect(target && typeof target === 'object').toBe(true)
```

**`null`**

```js
expect(target === null).toBe(true)
```

**`undefined`**

```js
expect(target === undefined).toBe(true)
```

**`function`**

```js
expect(typeof target).toBe('function')
```

**`Promise`** *or* **`async function`**

```js
expect(!!target && typeof target.then === 'function').toBe(true)
```

---

**Another example to match further types:**

**`float`** (*decimal number. i.e. `3.14`, `137.03`, etc.*)

```js
expect(Number(target) === target && target % 1 !== 0).toBe(true)
```

**`Promise`** *or* **`async function`** that return an **`Error`**

```js
await expect(asyncFunction()).rejects.toThrow(errorMessage)
```

---

**References:**

- https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobeinstanceofclass
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3457
- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/detect-if-value-is-a-promise-in-node-js-and-javascript

Comment: Can I also check if a variable is an instance of Date[] ?

Comment: This doesn't work for several of the scalar primitives, including Boolean, Number, and String, if those values are declared in the usual way as literals. `5 instanceof Number` is false, as is `'tom' instanceof String`. `typeof` works great for them. For trickier cases, use a library like lodash or [`is`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is)

Comment: @Tom The question asks about the `Date` object. of course you have to use the keyword `typeof` for certain cases.

Comment: typeof null === "object" 

Comment: Oddly neither the `toBeInstanceOf` or `instanceof` approaches worked as expected for me (Jest 27.4.5). I had to resort to `expect(mydate.constructor.name).toBe("Date")`

Comment: You really helped me!

Comment: For primitives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76028609/30946

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer works but is prone to typos. Especially with primitive types

```js
// This won't work. Misspelled 'string'
expect(typeof target).toBe("strng")
```

A better way that I found by chance in the documentation, which is not explicitly defined as a way to test types, is:

```js
expect(id).toEqual(expect.any(Number))
expect(title).toEqual(expect.any(String))
expect(feature).toEqual(expect.any(Boolean))
expect(date).toEqual(expect.any(Date))
```

Comment: I like this better :+1

Answer (score 6):

Jest supports `toBeInstanceOf`.  See [their docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobeinstanceofclass), but here is what they have for example at the time of this answer:

```
class A {}

expect(new A()).toBeInstanceOf(A);
expect(() => {}).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
expect(new A()).toBeInstanceOf(Function); // throws
```

Comment: This is limited to things which are instances of classes. You can't use it with `string`, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to check datatypes is to define a function and pass to it the object containing properties you want to check.

Using a similar approach like [@Mazen Sharkawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4858916/mazen-sharkawy)'s answer:

```
const validateDatatypes = ({ objToValidate }) => {
    expect(objToValidate).toEqual({
    property1: expect.any(String),
    property2: expect.any(Number),
    property2: expect.any(Date),
    // Every other check you need ...
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with JSX you can do the following

```
expect(result.type).toBe(MyComponent);
```

**Example**:

```
component = shallow(<MyWidget {...prop} />);

instance = component.instance();
const result = instance.myMethod();

expect(result.type).toBe(MyComponent);
```

In this example `myMethod()` return `MyComponent` and we are testing for it.